# how to convert string with html tag into file of pdf or doc type

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

how to convert a string that containing html tags into a pdf or doc file where html tags will convert into corresponding formating for example br tag to /n or newline bold tag to bold text in doc or pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use DOMPDF, a HTML to PDF converter.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site: [pdfcrowd.com](http://pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_input)

You can create your PDF directly online - by a given website, html file or input.

Comment: I am looking for a pdf converter that can convert my string into pdf programmatically